# FindByName control inside another control on ContentPage in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I want to set focus on SearchBar when he appears. The problem is that SearchBar is placed inside of popup view and I need to access him from ViewModel.

In standard way I would use

```
Xamarin.Forms.SearchBar tmp_SearchBar = this.Page.FindByName("fro_SearchBar_NewItem") as Xamarin.Forms.SearchBar;
```

but that's not working anymore.

Here is XAML

```
<sfPopup:SfPopupLayout x:Name="fro_Popup_NewItem" Opened="fro_Popup_NewItem_Opened" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Black">
    <sfPopup:SfPopupLayout.PopupView>
        <sfPopup:PopupView  BackgroundColor="Black" WidthRequest ="400" HeightRequest ="100" ShowFooter="False" ShowHeader="False">
            <sfPopup:PopupView.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!--Search bar-->
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <SearchBar  x:Name="fro_SearchBar_NewItem"
                                            Grid.Column="0"
                                            Text="{Binding SearchText_Popup, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                            SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}"
                                            Placeholder="Find" 
                                            CancelButtonColor="White" 
                                            TextColor="White" 
                                            PlaceholderColor="Gray"/>

                        </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                 </DataTemplate>
            </sfPopup:PopupView.ContentTemplate>
        </sfPopup:PopupView>
    </sfPopup:SfPopupLayout.PopupView>
</sfPopup:SfPopupLayout>
```

Nested FindByName doesn't work either.

```
Syncfusion.XForms.PopupLayout.SfPopupLayout tmp_Popup = _Page.FindByName("fro_Popup_NewItem") as Syncfusion.XForms.PopupLayout.SfPopupLayout;
Xamarin.Forms.SearchBar tmp_SearchBar = tmp_Popup.FindByName("fro_SearchBar_NewItem") as Xamarin.Forms.SearchBar;
```

Thanks

Comment: first, you really should never need to use `FindByName` directly.  Second, if you're using MVVM you shouldn't be trying to directly access the View from the VM - that is what data binding is for.  If you are just trying to set focus, that can be done in the code behind.  SfPopup has several lifecycle events you could use to do this.

Comment: yes, I could use 'Opened' event of popup but still, how to access searchbox from that ?

Comment: Give the search bar an x:Name then use it on the On appearing function of the code behind of the popup

Comment: That's what I did but its null.

private void fro_Popup_NewItem_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            var searchbar = fro_Popup_NewItem.FindByName("fro_SearchBar_NewItem");
            searchbar = this.FindByName("fro_SearchBar_NewItem"); 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this wasn't so far from right direction, neither of the comments actually.

```
Syncfusion.XForms.PopupLayout.SfPopupLayout tmp_Popup = _Page.FindByName("fro_Popup_NewItem") as Syncfusion.XForms.PopupLayout.SfPopupLayout;
Xamarin.Forms.SearchBar tmp_SearchBar = tmp_Popup.FindByName("fro_SearchBar_NewItem") as Xamarin.Forms.SearchBar;
```

but I found the one which works and I don't have to create separate XAML for Popup.

```
private void fro_Popup_NewItem_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var nativeObject = (object)fro_Popup_NewItem.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("NativeObject")).GetValue(fro_Popup_NewItem);
            var formsPopupviewContentTemplate = nativeObject.GetType().GetRuntimeFields().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("formsPopupViewContentTemplate")).GetValue(nativeObject);
            var SearchBar = (formsPopupviewContentTemplate as Grid).FindByName<SearchBar>("fro_SearchBar_NewItem");
            SearchBar?.Focus();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for help, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-6.0)** to open a new thread to complete this operation in code-behind.

Xaml:

```
  <SearchBar  x:Name="fro_SearchBar_NewItem" Placeholder="...." BackgroundColor="White"/>
```

Code behind:

```
   public partial class PagePop : Popup
   {
        public PagePop()
        {
             InitializeComponent();
             Task.Run(() => myTask());//Create and start the thread
        }
        private void myTask()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(300);
            fro_SearchBar_NewItem.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes, ofc. I was off few days.

Comment: Where should I put this PagePop class ? I tried to create custom control, content page where popup is placed but none of them works.

Comment: You guys prolly missing the point of the problem, I know how to access controls from code-behind (Content Page). I don't know how to access control which is inside of another control on Content Page, in this case SearchBar inside Popup. I can't reference controls from Content Page that are placed inside of Popup.
I was searching a lot about this topic and I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: I moved a little bit forward but I am not at the end still. I could create XAML page for entire popup and then I am able to use code-behind of popup to work with his controls, but I have arguments in PopupPage constructor and I can't use it that way on ContentPage XAML. It says - Type 'PopupPage' is not usable as an object element because it is not public or does not define a public parameterless constructor or a type converter.